# Cascoded op-amp: What practically limits CMRR and input impedance?

Tags: operational-amplifier, integrated-circuit, input-impedance, cascode, input-offset-voltage

I am interested to better understand the *practical* limitations to input impedance and common-mode rejection ratio in cascoded op-amp structures. I already simulated quite a bit, but I am running into convergence problems for some edge cases, and I am running the risk of GIGO in such scenarios, too.

To clear up some definitions, by input impedance I mean the *variation* of the input bias current \$\frac{dV_{IN+}}{dI_{IN+}}\$ and, by CMRR I mean the *variation* of the input offset voltage \$\frac{dV_{IN+}}{d(V_{IN+}-V_{IN-})}\$. And I always refer to the generic circuit diagram below.

It contains:

- input differential pair M1 & M2
- current mirror D & CCCS1
- cascode transistors Q1 & Q2
- cascode bias V1
- tail current I1
- The depicted input differential amplifier is part of a closed-loop operational amplifier with negative feedback, e.g. a voltage follower

### Questions:

1. Is it correct that both input impedance and CMRR would be *infinite*, if all three of the current mirror, V1 and I1 were *infinitely* stiff ?
2. Is it correct that the characteristics such as matching of the transistors, in contrast, don't matter ?
3. Is it correct that even at AC, the input capacitance of M1 & M2 don't really matter, as long as the cascode bias and currents remain stiff ?
4. If I am correct about (1-3), is there anything that practically (in terms of IC design) prevents a BJT op-amp from achieving something like TOhm input impedance over much of its common-mode range?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDUoZs.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Are you sure of the CMRR definition? Should not be (dVin+ + dVin-)/2 /  (dVin+ - dVin-)?

Comment: Q2 ... don't think so. Matching does matter and even matching temperature of the transistors (at lowest level) is important. Q3 ... until what frequency?

Comment: @Antonio51 yes, but my equation is probably equivalent. Since the common mode voltage moves along with VIN+ in the equilibrated circuit and since we are only interested in the change, we can replace the common-mode voltage with the voltage at any one of the inputs. About Frequency: no particular AC frequency. I am asking in general, but if you wish, or if it matters for an answer, make it 1 kHz.